# Problema com url amigável

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

Estou enfrentando problemas com url amigáveis em meu site.

Minhas requisições entram em loop se eu faço isso:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sessao.php
```

Se faço isso, não caio no loop, mas minha requisição não passa pelo meu sessao.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sessao.php
```

No entanto algo estranho acontece com meu servidor, mesmo sem o .htaccess e sem o módulo rewriter do apache ativo, se eu chamar meudominio.com.br/pagina ele vai busca primeiro pagina.html se não encontrar ele vai buscar pagina.php.

Eu acredito que os erros estão selecionados.
Eu uso apache 2.22, PHP 5.4.9 no ubuntu 12.04 e 13.04(Testei nas duas dist e dá o mesmo problema) no Cloud [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Amigos, 
conseguir resolver o problema, na verdade o meu problema esta no arquivo de configuração do site-available, dentro do nó de configuração tinha uma diretiva Multiviews, segundo o conselho de um amigo ao remover tal diretiva o problema seria resolvido.

Recorrendo ao editor nano (Inglês) executei o seguinte comando para editar as configuração:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Removi o Multiview do nó de configuração e após reinicialização do apache o assunto ficou resolvido

Comment: Relacionado a esse tópico? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7987/redirecionamento-estranho/8000#8000

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sessao.php [L,QSA]
```

Precisa mesmo desta linha abaixo?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```