# Redirecionamento estranho

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Mesmo sem o .htaccess e sem o módulo rewriter do apache ativo se eu chamar meudominio.com.br/pagina ele vai busca primeiro pagina.html se não encontrar ele vai buscar pagina.php.

Como desabilito esse "redirect", pois esta dando problema no meu .htacess

Eu uso apache 2.22, PHP 5.4.9 no ubuntu 12.04 e 13.04(Testei nas duas dist e dá o mesmo problema) no Cloud DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dadas as circunstâncias, acredito que seja causado pelo uso do "MultiViews"

exemplo:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Caso não queira utilizar, apenas remova-o

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

Caso o "redirecionamento" não seja causado pelo "MultiViews", provavelmente é alguma regra de reescrita de url (mod_rewrite).

Há outras possibilidades, mas acho difícil que seja algo fora dessas duas hipóteses.

off:
Desculpe comentar, mas não entendi o termo "defeito" nos comentários acima.
Isso é um termo usado em Portugal?
Em dicionários online, de português de Portugal, essa palavra tem o mesmo sentido do português do Brasil.
De qualquer forma, a palavra correta seria "default" (padrão).

[atualizando]
Um título mais apropriado para esse tópico seria "Apache interpretando um diretório como um arquivo .php ou .html".

Comment: Amigos, muito obrigado o problema foi exatamente o `Multiviews`. Recorrendo ao editor [nano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano)(Inglês) executei o seguinte comando para editar as configuração: `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. Removi o `Multivire` do nó de configuração e após reinicialização do apache o assunto ficou resolvido.

Answer (score 1):

O Apache por defeito vem configurado para trabalhar com o ficheiro `index.html`. Só se o mesmo não for localizado é que vai tentar localizar o `index.php`.

Uma forma rápida de resolveres isso é colocares na raiz do teu domínio um ficheiro `.htaccess` com a seguinte directiva:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Assim, ele deverá ir em primeiro ao `index.php`.

Se quiseres que ele ao falhar em localizar o `index.php` vá procurar o `index.html`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

---

Documentação para a [DirectoryIndex Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

> The DirectoryIndex directive sets the list of resources to look for, when the client requests an index of the directory by specifying a / at the end of the directory name.

Que traduzido:

> A directiva DirectoryIndex define a lista de recursos a procurar, quando o cliente solicita um índice do directório, especificando a `/` no final do nome do directório.

Comment: O valor padrão parece variar de instalação para instalação, pois [na documentação](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) só é especificado o `index.html`. Curiosamete na minha todos esses tem maior prioridade do que aquele: `index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml`.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues É verdade, varia de instalação para instalação, mas o que vejo sempre é que o `index.php` fica sempre para último. Da forma sugerida estamos basicamente a passar o mesmo para primeiro. (Devo dizer que pessoalmente uso como vem, `index.html` em primeiro, pois facilita com páginas de manutenção...) **Ps:** Obrigado pelo link para a documentação, vou meter na resposta :)

Comment: No XAMPP fica depois dessa lista que coloquei aí, então depois dele vem uma lista enorme de alternativas, `default.html` por exemplo. Queria saber o porque do `.php` ficar depois do `.html`. Defeito não é, seria compatibilidade?

Comment: Compatibilidade sim. Já não estou no computador mas amanhã posso elaborar a resposta nesse sentido.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues Já fiz uma pesquisa, mas não consegui encontrar nada "oficial" que corrobore a minha interpretação de ser uma questão de compatibilidade. Se encontrar adicionarei à resposta.